# required configurations for Kafka ConsumerInterceptor

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am new to Kafka. I have set up my environment to produce and consume records. But, my goal is to intercept records and modify their value before they are sent to the intended consumer.
For now, in order to make sure that the environment is well set up to intercept records I am writing a simple ConsumerInterceptor that will intercept records and println their values.
what should my configure() method implements to enable my consumerInterceptor? what other configuration should I add/modify and where?

```java
public class SimpleConsumerInterceptors<K, V> implements ConsumerInterceptor<K, V>{
    private String clientId;

    public void configure(final Map<String, ?> configs) {

// What configurations required to enable my consumerInterceptor?
        
    }

    public ConsumerRecords<K, V> onConsume(ConsumerRecords<K, V> records) {
        ConsumerRecords<K, V> interceptRecords = records;
        for (TopicPartition partition : records.partitions()) {
            String topic = partition.topic();
            List<ConsumerRecord<K, V>> recordsInPartition = records.records(partition);
            for (ConsumerRecord<K, V> record : recordsInPartition) {
                System.out.println("onConsume:");
                System.out.println(record.value());
            }
        }
                 
        return interceptRecords;
    }

    public void onCommit(Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets) {
        System.out.println("onCommit")
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("close")
        this.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is add the class name to the [`interceptor.classes` consumer property](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs), `ConsumerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG`.

You only have to implement `configure()` if you want to configure the interceptor after Kafka creates the instance.

The map passed into the method is the map of consumer properties.

So, let's say you want to make the logging optional; add `my.interceptor.logging.enabled=true` to the consumer config, and use it in the `configure()` method to configure whether the records are logged.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. It answered my question. However, for some reason, my interceptor is not working. I would appreciate your insight. Here's what I am doing:  (1) my command to start the consumer is : \./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic ConsumerInterceptor --from-beginning --property interceptor.classes=com.interceptor.kafka.springbootkafkainterceptor.LogConsumerInterceptors

Comment: My java code 
    `public ConsumerRecords<K, V> onConsume(ConsumerRecords<K, V> records) {

             
        ConsumerRecords<K, V> interceptRecords = (ConsumerRecords<K, V>) new ConsumerRecords<>( ImmutableMap.of( new TopicPartition("ConsumerInterceptor", 1),
               Arrays.asList( new ConsumerRecord<>(
                   "ConsumerInterceptor", 1, 1, 1l, TimestampType.CREATE_TIME, 
 1l,10, 10, "key", "123"))));
        return interceptRecords;
            
    }`

Comment: Don't put code in comments; as you can see; it's hard to read; I thought your question was about Spring (that's how you tagged it), but you are using the console consumer. There is no way to use an interceptor with the console consumer, only the Java consumer in `kafka-clients`.

Comment: Thanks for the info and sorry for putting my code in the comment.  I eventually need to write a KafkaConsumer but I thought I will test if the interception is working by the commandline first.  So I will write the KafkaConsumer . (also I found that you added a RecordInterceptor which might be better for my use case. so I will experiment with that also) as I said I am new to Kafka.  will get back to you on all. Thanks

Comment: Thank you I wrote my kafka spring consumer and followed your previous instructions for the interceptor and it is working